# Xcode Cloud No such Module Cocoapods library

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-cloud

I have a project using a Cocoapods as dependency manager and I am trying to create an Xcode Cloud workflow for it, everything look simple to configure and I added the ci_post_clone.sh to run the pod install command before start building.

Based on the logs all the dependencies are downloaded but whenever it starts building I have the **No such Module X error**, I am not sure what i did wrong but it looks like xcode Cloud misses the step of **Building targets in dependency order** and it starts building the main project before building the dependencies

Did anyone face this problem and how did you fix it

Thank you for your help

Comment: I used Xcode cloud for months and everything worked well until now. I encounter the same problem. I tried to to remove the dependency shown in the errors, but the error occurred on another dependency. In the logs "xcodebuild-build-for-testing.log" I can see `ComputeTargetDependencyGraph note: Building targets in dependency order`. I can see some of my dependencies not as a direct dependency of my target, but only in the "Pods-ProjectXXX" part. however, these missing dependencies are correctly put in the other linker flags of my target..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a temporary solution by adding the pod folder to my repository, this is not what most people are willing to do but for now it is working

Answer (score 0):

do you have a screenshot for how you set this up? Because the script file ci_post_clone.sh needs to exist in a repository named ci_scripts that is at the same level as your workspace / xcode project. You also need to be sure to mark that file as executable

then you can brew install cocoapods and run pod install on that script.  cheers! just got this working this morning by following notes found here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/making-dependencies-available-to-xcode-cloud

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `brew install cocopods` to your ci_post_clone.sh so that you can install it with `pod install`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9ypui7zSyg